# Can it be setup on the below .... DNS

Tags: dns, port-forwarding

Current we have

`www.abc.com.hk` --> Real-IP `10.10.10.10:80` --> PrivateIPsrv --> `193.168.13.8:80`

Now I have a new Sharepoint server setup and I would like the outsider can access it using

`abcSP2010.abc.com.hk` --> Real-IP `10.10.10.10:10080` --> PrivateIPsrv --> `193.168.13.188:80`

`abcSP2010adm.abc.com.hk` --> Real-IP `10.10.10.10:1234` --> PrivateIPsrv --> `193.168.13.188:1234`

1. Is that possible ?
2. Where I need to setup those setting.
3. How to set.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like you are using port forwarding on your router.

Examining the current router settings should reveal that port 80 is being forwarded to your web server.

Simply duplicate that setting replacing the port numbers with the ones for the new service.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the outsider to key in like 

www.abc.com.hk:10080
www.abc.com.hk:1234

but want them to key in

abcSP2010.com.hk or
abcSP2010adm.com.hk